# can't open netbeans IDE in Fedora 17

Tags: gnome3, java, troubleshooting

my linux version is: Fedora 17 
I installed Netbeans IDE 7.1.2 and it was working fine, but now, when I try to open it, nothing happens after double clicking on it.
I think updating the kernel may be the reason, my current kernel version is : 3.4.3
do you know the exact reason and how to solve it?

Comment: I dont think that the problem is the kernel, you should check your JDK version. Try to run netbeans command from command line and post the output..

Comment: bash: netbeans: command not found...
java command is not found too!

Comment: sounds like you did not install java/netbeans into your path, perhaps you did not install them using yum? unfortunately I'm not sure what the canonical way to do this in fedora is.

Answer (score 1):

If you have java installed, check the path for `netbeans_jdkhome` in `netbeans.conf`. 
You can find this file at `netbeans_installation_dir/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf`.

In `netbeans.conf`:

`netbeans_jdkhome="path_to_java"`

If `path_to_java` is incorrect, replace it with your actual java path.

**Note** this path is without `/bin` directory, so don't include `/bin` at the end of the path.

Comment: Welcome on the site! There are various, very goodlooking formatting options in the editor, I tried to tune your post with them. Furthermore, all capital nicks may not look the best on the first spot, I suggest to become simply "Amit Gurbani".